# Help with Iversonian notation in Concrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, notation

On page 36, the book presents this useful identity:
$$[1 \leq j \leq n][j \leq k \leq n]=[1 \leq j \leq k \leq n] = [1 \leq k \leq n][1 \leq j \leq k].\quad\text{(2.31)}$$

I was able to convince myself that the equalities are true. The left equality of equation (2.31) allows us to write
$$\sum_{1 \leq j \leq n}\sum_{j \leq k \leq n}a_{j,k}=\sum_{1 \leq j \leq k \leq n}a_{j,k}.$$

So far so good. My doubt arises on page 39 where the following sum is presented to be solved:
$$S_n=\sum_{1 \leq j < k \leq n}\frac{1}{k-j}.$$
Notice the strict inequality in the middle ($j < k$). On the next page, the book applies equation (2.31) to rewrite this summation as follows:
$$S_n=\sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}\sum_{1 \leq j < k}\frac{1}{k-j}.$$

When I tried this derivation myself, I rewrote $S_n$ using Iversonian notation as $\sum_{j}\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k-j}[1 \leq j < k \leq n]$ and proved that $[1 \leq j < k \leq n]=[1 < k \leq n][1 \leq j < k]$; the strict inequality on the left bracket of the right-hand side comes from the fact that $1 \leq j < k$ implies $1 < k$, but the derivation in the book suggests that $[1 \leq j < k \leq n]=[1 \leq k \leq n][1 \leq j < k]$. In fact, it's not hard to see that this second equality is also true. It's as if the inequality between $1$ and $k$ didn't make any difference. But if both these equalities are true, then
$$[1 < k \leq n][1 \leq j < k]=[1 \leq k \leq n][1 \leq j < k].$$
I thought this equality so... weird. When I put those back into the summations, doesn't that mean that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{k-j}$ will have an extra term compared to $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{k-j}$? What am I missing? (Note: further in the text, I see that this extra term makes no difference, but instead of $\frac{1}{k-j}$, imagine some other term $a_{j,k}$; my question still remains...)

In addition to this derivation, the book performs another one using the right equality of equation (2.31) with the intent of putting the index $j$ in the outer sum. An analogous situation happens! I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: This is also explained in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1699948/701444) for the similar case at the page 40 and page 41. Specifically, see "The inner summation is non-zero only for ..." part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The extra term will be when $k=1$, so the inner sum becomes : $$\sum_{j=1}^{1-1}\frac{1}{k-j} = \sum_{j=1}^{0}\frac{1}{k-j} = 0$$ because there is no integer between $1$ and $0$.

Comment: I fixed a typo in equation 2.31. But it is not supposed to be what you stated. Your expression leads to two sums whose indices are independent. If that was the case, I'd be able to easily exchange the sums without using equation 2.31.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to correct the typo in my answer, I will remove this comment as this is fixed in your question